# how to use 2 spinner for a fpersonal orm in android?

Tags: android, spinner

I want to create a personal form in my app. user should fill it down. I use 2 spinners (drop down button) for getting 2 items - marriage_state and sex_state. unfortunately as I run my app, spinners do not show anything to me. what can I do? how can i solve it?

my xml code:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/marriage"
            style="@style/Edittext_form"
            android:prompt="@string/marriage"
            android:entries="@array/marriage_state"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

        <Spinner
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:id="@+id/sex"
              style="@style/Edittext_form"
              android:prompt="@string/sex"
              android:entries="@array/sex_state"
              android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

my string code:

```
<string name="sex">جنسیت...</string>
<string-array name="sex_state">
    <item>زن</item>
    <item>مرد</item>
</string-array>
<string name="marriage">*وضعیت تاهل...</string>
<string-array name="marriage_state">
    <item>مجرد</item>
    <item>متاهل</item>
</string-array>
```

my java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Spinner _sex, _marriage;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    _sex = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sex);
    _marriage = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.marriage);

 ArrayAdapter<String> sex_spinner_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            R.array.marriage_state);
    _sex.setAdapter(sex_spinner_adapter);

    ArrayAdapter<String> marriage_spinner_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            R.array.marriage_state);
    _marriage.setAdapter(marriage_spinner_adapter);

 _sex.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    sex = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });

            _marriage.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    marriage = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }

            });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create adapter like below.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> marriage_spinner_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.marriage_state, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

//and then set adapter like below.
_marriage.setAdapter(marriage_spinner_adapter);
```

FYI : For both the adapter, you use same array as R.array.marriage_state.
Change them to respective arrays.

Comment: thanks a lot, but spinners do not show anything too. would you help me?